# A complex lie algebra is the direct sum of simple ideals iff it is semisimple

Tags: lie-algebras, ideals, direct-sum

I am trying to show that a complex Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ is the direct sum of simple ideals *iff* it is semisimple.

In fact, I have already proved that it is sufficient. I am now trying to prove that $\mathfrak g$ being a direct sum of simple ideals implies that it is semisimple.

*Currently, I would like to prove that if $J$ is an ideal of the direct sum of simple ideals, then $J$ is itself a direct sum of some subset of these simple ideals.*

So considering $J$ to be a direct sum of $L_i$, I am able to show that if $J$ is not equal to the direct sum of all the $L_i$, then there exists $i$ such that $[L_i,J]=0$.

From this how can I conclude that $J$ is contained in the direct sum of the $L_j$s with $j\neq i$?

Comment: Hint: The intersection of $J$ with any of those ideals $I$ will be an ideal of $I$.

Comment: Hi Tobias. Could you expand on your comment please. It is not inducing a light-bulb moment, unfortunately.

Comment: Well, each of the ideals are simple, so for each of them, the intersection must either be the entire ideal (so $J$ contains $I$), or it is $0$. Show that $J$ is the sum of those ideals it contains.

Comment: The fact that J is a sum of those ideas would just follow from the fact it has whole or empty intersection with each ideal?

Comment: Actually, I have overlooked something. Just because it has zero intersection with $L_i$, doesn't mean that ideal can't contribute to elements in $J$. (By this I mean, an element of $J$ could be of the form x + y where x is in direct sum of some ideals and y is in $L_i$.)
How exactly do we get round this?

Answer (score 7):

Let $L=L_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus L_n$ be the decomposition of a semisimple Lie algebra into simple ideals.
Let $J$ be an ideal of $L$.
For each $1\leq i\leq n$, $[JL_i]$ is an ideal of $L_i$, so either $[JL_i]=0$ or $[JL_i]=L_i$.
Let $I_0$ be the subset of $\{1,...,n\}$ for which $[JL_i]=0$ and $I_1$ be the subset of $\{1,...,n\}$ for which $[JL_i]=L_i$.

We claim $J=\oplus _{i\in I_1} L_i$.
Let $x\in J$.
Then $x=x_1+\cdots +x_n$ with $x_i\in L_i$, $1\leq i\leq n$.
We show $x_i=0$ for each $i\in I_0$.
Suppose $x_i\neq0$ for some $i\in I_0$.
Then $x_i\notin Z(L_i)$, because $Z(L_i)=0$ as a solvable ideal of $L$.
Hence, there exists $y\in L_i$ such that $[x_i,y]\neq0$.
Then $0=[x,y]=[x_1,y]+\cdots +[x_n,y]=[x_i,y]$, using $[JL_i]=0$ and $[L_jL_k]=0$ for $j\neq k$.
This is contradictory, so we must have $x_i=0$ for all $i\in I_0$, which gives $x=\sum_{i\in I_1}x_i$.
Therefore, $J\subseteq \oplus_{i\in I_1}L_i$. 
But since $[JL_i]=L_i$ implies $L_i\subseteq J$, we get $J= \oplus_{i\in I_1}L_i$.